# on ReactJS, can't handle a navigation to a div in page from the navigation bar

Tags: html, reactjs, navigation

I'm having trouble with a project where I need to navigate to a certain section of a page when a navigation item is clicked.

I am using the Navlink component as follows and can't put my hand on a solution.

In my navigation component Toolbar.js, I have the following code concerning the navigation item.

> Toolbar.js

```
           <li>
            <NavLink
              exact
              activeStyle={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'red',
                textDecoration: 'none'
              }}
              to="/"
            >
              agence
            </NavLink>
          </li>
```

Then I'm using the component as follows in Home.js :

> Home.js

```
return (
      <Layout>
        <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />
        <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
        {backDrop}
        <Conseil />
        <div className={classes.white}></div>
        <Sigles />
        <NotreAgence />
        <Prestations />
        <ScrollableMenu />
        <Form />
        <Footer />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is navigate to the "NotreAgence" component when I click on the "accueil" NavLink showed above.

I've tried to mimic the html :

```
<a href="#scroll">Go to Title</a>
<div>
  <h1 id="scroll">Title</h1>
</div>
```

as follows :

```
            <NavLink
              exact
              activeStyle={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'red',
                textDecoration: 'none'
              }}
              to={{
                pathname: '/',
                hash: '#our-agency'
              }}
            >
              agence
            </NavLink>
```

and giving a div tag the "#our-agency" tag.

But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm a bit stuck. Any help ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: please share your routing component

Comment: @VahidAkhtar hello, I've uploaded it on Github as a public dir [git](https://github.com/gryanab/cpm-paris/tree/master/src). The main routing component is in the **App.js file**. Should I add a similar one in my **Home.js** component to manage navigation inside of it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update to close this issue. One solution would be to use the `react-scroll` library.

In the Navigation menu/bar : 
import it => `import { Link } from 'react-scroll'`

Define your navigation item as follows (using the code of the question to make it more clear) :

`Toolbar.js`

```
import { Link } from 'react-router' 


(...)   


          <li>
            <Link
              exact
              activeStyle={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'red',
                textDecoration: 'none'
              }}
              to="notreAgence"
            >
              agence
            </Link>
          </li>
```

Give your component an id prop with a value  matching the `to` props from the `Link`. (Here it would be 'section1'.

`Home.js`

```
return (
  <Layout>
    ...
    <NotreAgence id='notreAgence' />
    ...
  </Layout>
);
```

}

This do the the trick.

For more information : https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-smooth-scrolling-in-react

Answer (score 0):

```
to={{
  pathname: '/',
  hash: '#our-agency'
}}
```

when you have / in link - it force to update page.
So if you want to reach section on current page you need use just

> to="#our-agency"

Comment: Thank you very much, but I've tried that also. Doesn't seem to work... 

In NotreAgence.js : 



`<section id="#our-agency">
      <div className={classes.image__agency}></div>
      <div className={classes.our__agency}></div>
</section>`

Comment: `id=our-agency` not `#our-agency`, sorry the edit is not taking effect